# Select cannot read property name of undefined neither render values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-functional-component

I have a user object in my MongoDB database and a trainee object. The trainee object has an "author" field where it references the user object.

So for example, if I wanted to show the author's name attached to my trainee object, I would do:

```
trainee.author.name
```

My issue is that I cannot show the names of the users in my dropdown, as menu items, they just don't appear. Also, I am receiving this error which originates from this:

```
<Select id="grouped-select" value={trainee.author.name || ''} renderValue={ () => renderValue(trainee.author.name)}>
```

The error originates from trainee.author.name, which by default will always be empty until I assign a user into it by selecting one from the dropdown.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong here? It doesn't look wrong to me.

Below I will be posting my full code with a brief explanation of what things do.

I am receiving a list of users from my API and I am updating the state with them:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([

  ])  

useEffect(() => {
  fetch('api/admin/users')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => setUsers(json))

}, [])
```

I am defining the state for my trainee.

```
const [trainee, setTrainee] = useState (
      {status: "Active"}
)
```

Handler function as to when a value from the dropdown of users is clicked. If I click on a specific user that is in the dropdown, then the entire user object is placed inside trainee.author

```
const renderValue = (value) => {
  return value;
}
const handleClick = (user) => {
    setTrainee({...trainee, 
      author: user});
}
```

Rendering the array of users and the select component with all their functions.

```
<Select id="grouped-select" value={trainee.author.name || ''} renderValue={ () => renderValue(trainee.author.name)}>
  <span>
    {users && users.length > 1 && users.map((user) => (
      <MenuItem key={user._id} onClick={()=>handleClick(user)} value={user.name}>
        {user.name}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </span>
        </Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

When your component renders, the data is not received yet. So there is no author in your trainee state. You can avoid it by checking it first

```
{tranee.author && 
<Select id="grouped-select" value={trainee.author.name || ''} renderValue={ () => renderValue(trainee.author.name)}>
  <span>
    {users && users.length > 1 && users.map((user) => (
      <MenuItem key={user._id} onClick={()=>handleClick(user)} value={user.name}>
        {user.name}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </span>
  </Select>}
```

Another point, use function if your next state depends on old one

```
const handleClick = (user) => {
    setTrainee(prevState => {...prevState, 
      author: user});
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work because trainee.author is by empty / undefined by default. I have to click on a MenuItem so the user object goes into trainee.author

Comment: Sorry, but when you define your state. I don't see author in your trainee